# I am trying to write this program but it keeps on displaying an a error everything is mentioned below can anyone check

Tags: c++

Question:

> Write a C++ program that stores and siplays following employee data of
> a company in structures:
>
> - Employee ID (int)
> - Employee Name (string)
> - Email (string)
> - Designation (char)
> - Salary (float)
> - Projects (array of strings)
>
> Your code must contain following:
>
> - Pointer to structure
> - Array of Structure
> - Structure variable

Source Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

struct EmployeeData
{
    int Eid;
    string Ename;
    string Eemail;
    string Desig;
    float salary{};
    string projects[10];
    };

int main()
{

    cout<<endl;
    struct EmployeeData *E,d;
    E=&d;
    int i=0;
    int counter=0;
    char a;
    do
    {
        cout<<"\nDETAIL OF EMPLOYEE #"<<i+1<<"\n"<<endl;
        cout<<"Employee ID: ";
        cin>>(*E).Eid;
        cout<<"Employee Name: ";
        cin>>(*E).Ename;
        cout<<"Employee Email: ";
        cin>>(*E).Eemail;
        cout<<"Designation: ";
        cin>>(*E).Desig;
        cout<<"Salary: ";
        cin>>(*E).salary;
        cout<<"Projects: ";
        cin>>(*E).projects[i];
        cout<<"To print detail of all employees press p: ";
        cin>>a;
        i++;
        counter++;
    }
    while(a!='p');
   cout<<"Employee ID"<<"Name"<<"Email"<<"Designation"<<"Salary"<<"Projects"<<endl;
   {
    cout<<(*E).Eid[i]<<(*E).Ename[i]<<(*E).Eemail[i]<<(*E).Desig[i]<<(*E).salary[i]<<(*E).projects[i]<<endl;
   }
    return 0;
    
}
```

Errors:

> 10    15  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] non-static data
> member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
>
> 10    14  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] extended initializer
> lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
>
> 10    15  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp   [Warning] extended initializer
> lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
>
> C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp In function 'int main()':
>
> 48    21  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp   [Error] invalid types
> 'int[int]' for array subscript
>
> 48    83  C:\Users\hp\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp   [Error] invalid types
> 'float[int]' for array subscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The first three errors indicate you're trying to brace-initialize the `float` member without C++11 compilation. Either enable C++11 compilation or change:

```
float salary{};
```

To

```
float salary;
```

2. The final two errors indicate you're incorrectly attempting to index something with `[i]`. Change:

```
cout<<(*E).Eid[i]<<(*E).Ename[i]<<(*E).Eemail[i]<<(*E).Desig[i]<<(*E).salary[i]<<(*E).projects[i]<<endl;
```

to

```
cout<<(*E).Eid<<(*E).Ename<<(*E).Eemail<<(*E).Desig<<(*E).salary<<(*E).projects<<endl;
```